# How to modify the Date Modified in Bulk?

Tags: android, windows, metadata, android-gallery, windows-explorer

A few days back I took a backup of my phone's documents before a factory reset of my phone.
But when I copied the files on to my Windows system, the "Date of Creation" of those files changed to the time I copied. I noticed it when the factory reset was complete and I copied my backup back to the phone. 
Here's a screenshot of properties panel. Note that in the properties window, the 'created' time is newer than the 'modified' date...
[image]

The 'Modified' time you see in the window was actually the date of 'last modified' on my phone but the date of creation has changed. In my phone's gallery, the images are by default set to be organised by "Date of Creation" which has changed now. Hence, I have lost all my organisation on my phone.
It may be recovered if I find a way through which I can set back the 'Created' date to same as 'Modified Date' in bulk for all the documents.
Is there a way???

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find freeware software called BulkFIleCHanger. I have used it before, and it's working. But I'm not sure if I can paste 3rd party links here, you can find it easy anyway.
Use function "Copy Time From..."

Comment: Thanks for your response :-) I will be trying it for sure.